# NumericUpDown how to setvalue

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I have a numericupdown box and I am trying to load the value of it each time the form loads.

I have tried the following with no joy

```
   string striko1value = clsData.GetStriko1GasReading();
        decimal striko1 = decimal.Parse(striko1value);
        Striko1Numeric.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(striko1);
```

I have also tried this

```
Striko1Numeric.Value = (striko1);
```

Anyone have any ideas about how I would do this or where I could read up on this.

Comment: Set a breakpoint over the first line of your code. Step over that instruction (F10) and then look at the value assigned to `stiko1value`. Tell us what you see.

Comment: Where are you executing this code?

Comment: Did that steve before i asked the question it holds the value that i want it too. The value stays there until the Convert.ToDecimal(striko1); then it does not set the value in the numeric updown

Comment: what value your getting in "striko1"

Comment: Check the value of "Convert.ToDecimal(striko1)"

Comment: After your assignment to `Striko1Numeric.Value`, if you re-read the property you've just set, is the value correct? I ask because it's possible that the code does exactly what you want, but some code that is later executed is setting the control to a different value.

Comment: What is your Maximum and Minimum value?

Comment: The value is still set to the figure it should for a test the value is 9999. striko1 stays 9999 in Convert.ToDecimal(striko1) it is also 9999

Comment: try to hard code that and see

Striko1Numeric.Maximum=100;
Striko1Numeric.Minimum = 0;
Striko1Numeric.Value = 10;

Comment: Thanks Bilal Hashmi got it thanks

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that your `clsData.GetStriko1GasReading()` effectively returns a string that can be interpreted as a decimal value, then you probably have a value that is outside the Minimum or Maximum value allowed to the NumericUpdown control

```
 string striko1value = clsData.GetStriko1GasReading(); 
 decimal striko1;
 if(decimal.TryParse(striko1value, out striko1))
 {
    if(striko1 > Striko1Numeric.Maximum ||  striko1 < Striko1Numeric.Minimum)
       MessageBox.Show("Value not allowed");
    else
        Striko1Numeric.Value = striko1; 
 }
 else
    MessageBox.Show("Not a valid decimal number");
```

Answer (score 0):

got it guys the Maximum value that i allowed was less than the value that was at striko1.

Thaks for the help